# Heroku ImportError: cannot import name 'app'

Tags: heroku, flask

I have a flask project with the following structure:

```
/27_shop_score
    /app
        /static
        /tasks
        /templates
        __init__.py
        routes.py
    .flaskenv
    Procfile
    shop_score.py
```

Contents of the `.flaskenv` is `FLASK_APP=shop_score.py`

Contents of the `shop_score.py` is `from app import app`

The app is being initialized in `/27_shop_score/app/__init__.py` as `app = Flask(__name__)`.

I'm getting the following error in `heroku logs --tail`:

```
2019-03-16T12:51:26.909725+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/shop_score.py", line 6, in <module>
2019-03-16T12:51:26.909726+00:00 app[web.1]: from app import app
2019-03-16T12:51:26.909730+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

Of course, locally this issue is absent.

The `sys.path` is `['/app/.heroku/python/bin', '/app', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`.

`os.listdir(sys.path[1])` is
`['.profile.d', 'robots.txt', 'README.md', '.gitignore', '__pycache__', 'celeryconfig.py', 'requirements.txt', '.editorconfig', 'runtime.txt', '.flaskenv', 'shop_score.py', 'Procfile', 'app', '.heroku']`.

The whole app is here: https://github.com/mxmaslin/27_shop_score

Can you please give me a clue of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) seems to be missing

Comment: sorry, forgot to include it to my description. Also, added a link to project's sources.

Comment: are you able to run it locally with foreman ?

Comment: I'm launching it locally by `flask run`. Will try foreman.

Comment: In the Github link, the file `__init__.py` is named as `__Init__.py`. Not sure if this maybe causing it.

Comment: silly me. Thank you, @amanb!

Comment: Did that solve the problem? Is the app now running on Heroku?

Comment: it solved the problem, but I got another issue, not related to it